# how to make background image responsible and not scaling down too much

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm working on responsible website and I'm using 'waves' SVG images for a `background-image`. Everything's fine until the viewport is small, i.e on mobile devices background is too small and you can barely see it.

I'm using 2 sometimes 3 `background-images`, depends on subpage. This is how my css looks.

```
background-image:
    url('../Img/Background/wave.svg'),
    url('../Img/Background/wave2.svg');

background-position:
    top 32% left 0%,
    top 80% left 0%;

background-repeat: no-repeat;

background-size: 100%;
```

I think this is the only approach how you can add and style multiple backgrounds separately. I've tried to look up here on Stackoverflow, because there are many similar questions but nothing really helps me.

**Example when device has big screen :**

[image]

**Example of tablet screen**

[image]

**Example of mobile phone screen**

[image]

As you can see `background-image` is scaling too much and it's very thin against the original size. Is it because of `background-size:100%` ? I've tried to set fixed width but then, background was not full page width..

How I can prevent this shrinking on smaller devices or make this backgrounds bigger on smaller devices ?
Am I supposed to set some different background-images in media queries on specific breakpoint?

Thanks.

Comment: Set `background-position` and `background-size` using media queries according to viewport OR use `background-size:contain`

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size:cover;
```

Or you can try

```
background-size:contain;
```

Another thing that could help and usually helps me get backgrounds with shapes nice and snug on mobile is:

```
 background-attachment: fixed;
```